# Uncaught TypeError: addresses.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

I have problem with .js script (for google maps) in another view this script works correctly (but there we have few locations)

I have an error like this

> Uncaught TypeError: addresses.forEach is not a function
>
> ```
> at getAllAddresses (map-localizations.js:26)
> at setMarkersOnMap (map-localizations.js:49)
> at Object.<anonymous> (map-localizations.js:19)
> at fire (jquery.js:3317)
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3447)
> at done (jquery.js:9272)
> at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:9514)
> ```

My map-localizations.js file which I have use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $googleMap = $('.google-map');
var map = new google.maps.Map($googleMap[0], {
    zoom: 0,
    center: {lat: 0, lng: 0}
});

initMap();

function initMap() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/ajax/company-localizations',
        data: {id: $googleMap.data('id')}
    }).done(function(addresses) {
        setMarkersOnMap(addresses, geocoder);
    });
}

function getAllAddresses(geocoder, addresses) {
    var deferreds = [];

    addresses.forEach(function(address) {
        if (!address.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
            deferreds.push(geocodeAddress(geocoder, address));
        }
    });

    return deferreds;
}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, address) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        deferred.resolve(results[0]);
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}

function cutUndefined(element, index, array) {
    return (typeof element !== 'undefined')
}

function setMarkersOnMap(addresses, geocoder) {
    var deferreds = getAllAddresses(geocoder, addresses);

    $.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function() {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var locations = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).filter(cutUndefined);
        var markers = [];

        locations.forEach(function(location, index) {
            bounds.extend(location.geometry.location);
            markers.push(
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: location.geometry.location,
                    status: 'active',
                    zoom: 10,
                    label: location.formatted_address
                })
            )
        });

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        map.panToBounds(bounds);

        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(
            map,
            markers,
            {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'}
        );
    });
}
```

});

I have attach my js file to my view

```
$this->registerJsFile('js/map-localizations.js',
[
    'depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className(), \yii\web\YiiAsset::className()],
    'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_END
]);
```

And show at the page like 
`<div id="localizations-map" class="google-map" google-maps data-id="" data-address="<?php echo $company->street; ?>, <?php echo $company->house_no; ?> <?php $company->local_no ? '/' . $company->local_no : ''; ?> <?php echo $company->postal_code; ?> <?php echo $company->cityEntity->cityEntity->name; ?>">
                    </div>`

Comment: You assume `addresses` is an array, but it is not. Therefore, it has no `forEach` function. Just print it and make sure it is what you are expecting it is.

Comment: `setMarkersOnMap(addresses, geocoder)` should be `setMarkersOnMap(geocoder, addresses)`

Comment: Add a log in `initMap` function and see the value of addresses. Add the same in question above

Comment: Please check what type `addresses` is as `.forEach` is a function on the `Array.prototype`.